# How can I use Source Sans Pro in Tex-Live 2012?

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive, ubuntu, sourcesanspro

I use TeX Live 2012 on an updated Ubuntu 12.10 machine with Latexila. I intended using Adobe's open source font Source Sans Pro in my latest paper.

I followed the instruction on the [LaTeX Font Catalogue page](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/sourcesanspro/), inserted

```
\usepackage[default,oldstyle]{sourcesanspro}
```

but Latexila only spits out the following error:

```
File 'sourcesanspro.sty' not found.
```

I already installed all LaTeX extra packages, I could find with `apt-get`.

Any ideas?

Comment: how did you installed `sourcesanspro`? I suppose that Ububtu dosn't have that package in the current version. If so, install it by yourself

Comment: Ay, I thought it would come with `apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra` as this package got displayed when I searched for `apt-cache search Source Sans`. Probably though, this did not suffice!

Comment: no, that is the major difference between Ubuntu-TeXLive and TUG-Texlive from http://tug.org/texlive. Ubuntu updates it only one time per year and TUG daily!

Comment: get ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/fonts/sourcesanspro.zip unzip it and put the the files in the same directories of `~/texmf/...`. Then run `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=SourceSansPro.map`

Comment: You can follow the [quick install guide](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) to install vanilla TeX Live. Also read the [additional information for Ubuntu](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html#vanilla). If you have questions about the `sourcesanspro` package you can ask me in [the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends). Manual install is easiest with [the TDS zip](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/fonts/sourcesanspro.tds.zip). If you're brave try [the development version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pek8cfgujqw5krm/SourceSansPro.tds.zip).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should get an updated version of TexLive - which you obviously did not do before. The latest version includes Source Sans Pro.

It is however not in the official repository for 12.04 and 12.10, so you have to add an unofficial one:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:texlive-backports/ppa
```

After that, you can install TexLive with `apt`, not forgetting to get the font package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install texlive
$ sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-extra
```

You can now use Source Sans Pro:

```
% LaTeX
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
```

Or for XeLaTeX:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\setsansfont{Source Sans Pro}
```

Comment: As the maintainer of the `sourcesanspro` package I'd like to point out that `\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}` uses the OpenType fonts if you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Does it mean, the special command for XeLaTeX is not needed? I may delete it from my answer - or you can do so.

Answer (score 1):

With TeX Live installed, you can use [tlmgr](https://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html) to manage LaTeX packages.

```
tlmgr install sourcesanspro
```