# Problem installing adobe sourcesanspro in TeX Live 2012

Tags: fonts, pdftex, installing, texlive

I'm using TeX Live 2012 on CrunchBang Linux (which is a derivative of Debian wheezy), and trying to get Adobe Source Sans Pro running, following this post: [How can I use Source Sans Pro in Tex-Live 2012?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84186/how-can-i-use-source-sans-pro-in-tex-live-2012). That is, I manually installed the package in local texmf (added mweights.sty as well), ran texhash and enabled the map.

Everything seems to have installed correctly, but when I try to compile a .tex file with pdflatex, I get this error message:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 SourceSansPro- Regular-lf-t1--base
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for SourceSansPro-Regular-lf-t1--base.
mktexpk: perhaps SourceSansPro-Regular-lf-t1--base is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file SourceSansPro-Regular-lf-t1--base): Font SourceSansPro-Regular-lf-t1--base at 600 not found
```

I have searched for a similar issue, but didn't find anything mentionning this, so I suppose it's something in my configuration.

Could someone help me to see what I have done wrong?

Comment: The error means the font was not completely installed. The most likely problem is expressed in the third line of the error message. Did your run updmap after your manual installation to enable SourceSansPro.map?

Comment: I ran `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=SourceSansPro.map`, with the following output (when I run it now): `updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.`
SourceSansPro-Regular-lf-t1--base appears _not_ to be missing from the map file, and the files it points to are present as well.

Comment: If you extracted the package to `~/texmf` you might want to try running `updmap --enable Map=SourceSansPro.map` (as yourself).

Comment: @Silex: I installed the package in /usr/local/share/texmf. And running `updmap` (and not `sudo updmap-sys`) resolved everything. Strangely enough, I had tried to install another font (EBGaramond) and had the same problem. Running `updmap --enable Map=SourceSansPro.map`, as user, resolved also the mapping problem for EBGaramond. Thanks.

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary and can create problems. Generally, it is only advisable if you don't have permission to install outside your home directory. Does /usr/local/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg get created when you run updmap-sys? It isn't using that file but that's what I'd expect it to use if it weren't for the /etc one. If so, your distro is misconfiguring something somewhere and you should tell them. (Actually, you should probably do this anyway if this seems to be a distro-issue rather than a configuration one.)

Comment: @cfr: No, updmap-sys didn't create /usr/local/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg. I don't know if I got this correctly: what sort of problems could there be in using updmap instead of updmap-sys? In case of a TeXLive upgrapde, I guess. I see this problem is a recurring one: [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55881/local-font-installation-problems?rq=1) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133724/font-installation-problem-updating-map-file?rq=1) for instance. I'm using the standard Debian wheezy TeXLive, but I see that at least the OS X version also has comparable issues.

Comment: Well you have to remember to run it every time tex packages including fonts are installed or updated on your system. Otherwise you may end up using map files which don't match what you have installed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a highly localized issue resolved in the comments.

Comment: Indeed it is resolved for me. I tried to rephrase the title to make it more relevant, but don't know if I succeeded. I'm sorry if the question was outside the scope of this forum, and all the more grateful for the answers I received. The relationship with (La)TeX for me was the particuar way it handles fonts, but maybe those basics are better covered elsewhere. I see no problem in closing the topic if it seems best so.